# Unexpected JS outcome in IE/EDGE

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I wonder if someone can advise me on this? 
I have the below JS which changes my main logo when the page scrolls. 
It works as expected in Safari, Chrome, FireFox... but for IE and EDGE instead of my logos I get an empty box. 
I know that IE has some differences in CSS but is it the same type of issue for JS too? Appreciate any assistance.

```
 window.onscroll = function(){
    if ($("body").hasClass("my-desktop")) {
        if(window.scrollY >= 52) { 
            $("#my-logo-img").attr("src", "http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/themes/mytheme/Logo-1.png");
        } else {
            $("#my-logo-img").attr("src", "http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/themes/mytheme/Logo-2.png");
        }
    }
};
```

Many thanks

Comment: No clue whether this would help, but you probably should be using `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

Comment: `scrollY` isn't supported in IE. Try using `pageYOffset` instead. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY: "For cross-browser compatibility, use window.pageYOffset instead of window.scrollY."